# Origin of the name of Lord Balaji

Tags: vishnu, name, venkateshwara

Does the name Lord Balaji come from Lord of 'Bal Lao Jee' (please bring hair), which later transformed to Balaji? I am trying to find the origin of this specific name of Lord Vishnu

Comment: "Bal Lao Jee" seems a joke made by someone. It should be "Baala" + "Ji", which means "Respected Child".